# Search for one photo out of two on Python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have two photos and I want the pyautogui library to find one of the two photos, not one after the other, how do I do that?

I tried to make the program click on the buttons, but it turned
out that it finds them in turn, I expected that it would click on the second one if it did not find the first one

Comment: Going to need a much more elaborate description of your problem. Is this an issue using   `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()`? Please provide a minimum example of actual code (as text not a screenshot) that replicates your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked on mine

```
import pyautogui

# Assuming 'photo1.png' and 'photo2.png' are the filenames of your two photos

try:
    # Try finding and clicking the first photo
    first_photo_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('photo1.png')
    pyautogui.click(first_photo_location)
except TypeError:
    # second photo
    second_photo_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('photo2.png')
    pyautogui.click(second_photo_location)
```

Comment: sorry still new to stack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).